# What evidence is there for volēre over volere?

Tags: example-request, conjugation, vulgar-latin, romance-languages

In [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/11282/406), fdb mentions the Classical verb *volō, velle* transforming into **voleō, volēre* in Vulgar Latin. The main evidence for this is a form *volendi* in Augustine and reflexes like *voglio, volere* in modern Italian.

But how do we know that the verb was **voleō, volēre* and not **voliō, volere*? To my understanding, both would allow for both a gerund *volendi* and the Romance descendants.

Comment: The gerund of a 3rd conjugation I-stem would be expected to be *voliendi,* right? Like *capiendi*

Comment: @sumelic Potentially, but iirc in Vulgar Latin there was a lot of alternation between i-stems and non-i-stems (eventually resulting in the third conjugation breaking up and disappearing entirely as its own thing in Romance).

Comment: I think the idea is that there was an analogy with *habeō*, i.e. *habuī : habēre :: voluī : volēre*.

Comment: @TKR That would certainly make sense (and could make a good answer!)

Comment: Fr. vouloir must be from volēre, like avoir from habēre.

Comment: @fdb That would also make a good answer!

Comment: @fdb and of course there's Fr. pouvoir - OFr. poeir or pooir, CL posse, LL *pot**ē**re

Comment: If I understand the development of French vowels correctly, Present-Day French -oir goes back to ẹ; in other words, it must correspond to ĭ or  ē in Classical Latin before they merged in Late (Vulgar) Latin.

Comment: @AlexB. That would *also* make a good answer!

Comment: @Draconis Let me think a little bit more about this.

Answer (score 5):

A Latin form **volĕre* would have been stressed on the first syllable. Italian *volere* is stressed on the penultimate syllable, like a Latin form **volēre.* There could have been a Vulgar Latin form **volĕre* that was later replaced with *voˈl[e]re,* but it seems more parsimonious to just give **volēre* as the ancestor of the Italian and French forms.

"[The Destiny Of Latin Second Conjugation Infinitives In Romance](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/73341667.pdf)", by S. Davis and Donna Jo Napoli, goes through the etymology of the Italian verbs whose infinitives end in *-ere* with penultimate stress. According to Davis and Napoli, there are only 22 such verbs.

- 18 are from verbs with attested Latin infinitive forms in *-ēre.*
- 2 are from verbs with attested Latin infinitive forms in *-ĕre*: *saˈpere* vs. Latin *sapĕre* and *caˈdere* vs. Latin *cadĕre.*  *Sapio* is an *-io* verb in Latin, but *cado* isn't.
- 2 are from verbs with Latin infinitives not ending in *-re*: *poˈtere* vs. Latin *posse* and *voˈlere* vs. Latin *velle*

The root *vol-* does fit the phonological criteria that Davis and Napoli identify as relevant for the shift of *cadere* and *sapere* from the root-stressed to the theme-stressed category.